# Next.js withPageAuthRequired with getStaticProps

Tags: next.js, auth0, getstaticprops

According documentation [@auth0/nextjs-auth0](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0) we can use `withPageAuthRequired` for trigger login screen on pages required login.

short variant: `export const getServerSideProps = withPageAuthRequired();`

But what to do if I need to use `getStaticProps` for pre-render page at build time which can't be used together with getServerSideProps? Is there any way to use `withPageAuthRequired` on request static generated pages?

Right now I am using double check on client side for check auth. But I would rather use a server side check as i use on other pages.

P.S. There is way to use `withPageAuthRequired` on client side as well. This is not suitable for my use

Answer (score 3):

Since `getStaticProps()` is used to build a static page (i.e., no server-side logic/rendering at request time), the auth check and redirect to login will have to happen on the client side.

You might be able to get the behaviour you want by sticking a proxy in front of the static resource (e.g., using Lambda@Edge), though I'm not very familiar with this approach yet.

---

From your question it sounds like you are already familiar with how to do the check/redirect on the client side, but for the benefit of others who come across this post in the future:

To fetch user information on the client side, add a `<UserProvider>` to your app, and call the `useUser()` hook in client-side components.

See [docs](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/#basic-setup):

> Wrap your `pages/_app.js` component with the `UserProvider` component:
>
> ```
> // pages/_app.js
> import React from 'react';
> import { UserProvider } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
>
> export default function App({ Component, pageProps }) {
>   return (
>     <UserProvider>
>       <Component {...pageProps} />
>     </UserProvider>
>   );
> }
> ```
>
> You can now determine if a user is authenticated by checking that the
> `user` object returned by the `useUser()` hook is defined. You can
> also log in or log out your users from the frontend layer of your
> Next.js application by redirecting them to the appropriate
> automatically-generated route:
>
> ```
> // pages/index.js
> import { useUser } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';
>
> export default function Index() {
>   const { user, error, isLoading } = useUser();
>
>   if (isLoading) return <div>Loading...</div>;
>   if (error) return <div>{error.message}</div>;
>
>   if (user) {
>     return (
>       <div>
>         Welcome {user.name}!
>         <a href="/api/auth/logout">Logout</a>
>       </div>
>     );
>   }
>
>   return <a href="/api/auth/login">Login</a>;
> }
> ```
>
> For other comprehensive examples, see the [EXAMPLES.md](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md)
> document.

An alternative approach that uses `withPageAuthRequired()` on the client side:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withPageAuthRequired } from '@auth0/nextjs-auth0';

import Layout from '../components/layout';

export default withPageAuthRequired(function Profile({ user }) {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <h1>Profile</h1>
      <h4>Profile</h4>
      <pre data-testid="profile">{JSON.stringify(user, null, 2)}</pre>
    </Layout>
  );
});
```

Linked from [additional examples](https://github.com/auth0/nextjs-auth0/blob/main/EXAMPLES.md#protecting-a-client-side-rendered-csr-page).

Comment: I understand how work next js static generation. My idea was to use custom server to detect session or cookies from request to check authentication status and base on this return page or redirect to login. I wonder does anyone have an experience in such way. P.S. I don't use Client side check because we get jsx instead of html page created by SSG.